# Extending the Life of Pens

Tags: hardware

Pens these days frankly, suck. I can't use one for more than a day without it starting to bleed or just completely stop working, and I do not want to go and buy another pack of pens (although they are cheap, it's annoying). Anyone got any helpful tips to make my pen live another day?

edit: I do not want to get better pens. This questions extends to the scope of how I can easily make cheap pens last longer.

Comment: Erm, buy better pens? Papermate flexigrip for instance - they last ages, though I guess it depends how much writing you do with them, but I've never known one leak or just refuse to work like cheap ones do.

Comment: Buy better pens and keep them pointing down when not in use. I feel if your pens are just too bad in quality to begin with, there's not much you can do.

Comment: I believe my question is different but I'll try that for now. The point is, my pens aren't already dead. I would like to extend the life of pens that are still working so that they won't become dead, or at least don't do so for longer.